# Drupal 8 - composer update throwing error

Tags: drupal, composer-php, drupal-8

I am trying to update my drupal site using composer update command but getting error while updating drupal/core. I want to run composer update command successfully to add more dependencies.

I cannot paste entire log here but posting only error part for your reference:

```
...
- Upgrading symfony/http-kernel (v3.4.43 => v3.4.46): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/dependency-injection (v3.4.43 => v3.4.46): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/class-loader (v3.4.43 => v3.4.46): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading pear/archive_tar (1.4.9 => 1.4.10): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading masterminds/html5 (2.7.3 => 2.7.4): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge (1.0.4 => 1.1.1): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading laminas/laminas-feed (2.12.2 => 2.12.3): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading egulias/email-validator (2.1.18 => 2.1.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading doctrine/annotations (1.10.3 => 1.11.1): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading drupal/core (8.9.2 => 8.9.8): Extracting archive
  - Applying patches for drupal/core
    https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-02-07/2869592-remove-update-warning-34.patch (2869592 - Disabled update module shouldn't produce a status report warning)
   Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-02-07/2869592-remove-update-warning-34.patch
  - Upgrading squizlabs/php_codesniffer (3.5.5 => 3.5.8): Extracting archive
  - Installing sirbrillig/phpcs-variable-analysis (v2.9.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading drupal/coder (8.3.9 => 8.3.11):     Update failed (The .git directory is missing from D:\wamp64\www\drupal\vendor\drupal\coder, see https://getcomposer.org/commit-deps for more information)
    Would you like to try reinstalling the package instead [yes]? yes
  - Removing drupal/coder (8.3.9)
  - Installing drupal/coder (8.3.11): Cloning 67c1bcf2d6 from cache
    0 [>---------------------------]

  [Exception]
  Cannot apply patch 2869592 - Disabled update module shouldn't produce a status report warning (https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-02-07/2869592-remove-update-warning-34.patch)!


update [--with WITH] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-install] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [-w|--with-dependencies] [-W|--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Here is my composer.json file for your reference. Kindly check and help me sort out this issue.

```
{
    "name": "feroze/my-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 sites built with Lightnest.",
    "type": "project",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": {
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        "asset-packagist": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        },
        "brilsergei": {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "brilsergei/county",
                "version": "master",
                "type": "drupal-library",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/brilsergei/county/archive/master.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "require": {
                    "composer/installers": "^1.2.0"
                }
            }
        },
        "kbwood": {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "kbwood/countdown",
                "version": "master",
                "type": "drupal-library",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/kbwood/countdown/archive/master.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "require": {
                    "composer/installers": "^1.2.0"
                }
            }
        },
        "lightnest": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "..."
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1",
        "lightnest/lightnest": "^3.7.0",
        "acquia/blt": "^11.6.0",
        "acquia/drupal-spec-tool": "*",
        "acquia/lightning": "^4.0.0",
        "drupal/config_split": "^1.0.0",
        "drupal/core": "^8.6.0",
        "drupal/devel": "^2.0.0",
        "drupal/qa_accounts": "^1.0.0-alpha1",
        "bower-asset/jquery.easing": "^1.3.0",
        "bower-asset/blazy": "^1.8.0",
        "bower-asset/chosen": "^1.8.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "acquia/blt-require-dev": "^11.0.0-alpha1"
    },
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.2"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "composer-extensions/*.composer.json"
            ],
            "recurse": true,
            "replace": false,
            "ignore-duplicates": false,
            "merge-dev": true,
            "merge-extra": false,
            "merge-extra-deep": false,
            "merge-scripts": false
        },
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "initial": {
                "sites/default/default.services.yml": "sites/default/services.yml",
                "sites/default/default.settings.php": "sites/default/settings.php"
            }
        },
        "enable-patching": true,
        "installer-paths": {
            "docroot/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "docroot/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "docroot/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "docroot/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "docroot/profiles/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-profile"
            ],
            "docroot/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "docroot/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ],
            "docroot/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library",
                "type:bower-asset",
                "type:npm-asset"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ]
        },
        "installer-types": [
            "bower-asset",
            "npm-asset"
        ],
        "patchLevel": {
            "drupal/core": "-p2"
        },
        "patches": {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> [Exception]
> Cannot apply patch 2869592 - Disabled update module shouldn't produce a status report warning (https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-02-07/2869592-remove-update-warning-34.patch)!

That patch no longer applies on your version of Drupal Core. It looks like you will need to reroll the patch to apply to the Core release that you are trying to upgrade to.

See relevant issue according to the patch: [Disabled update module shouldn't produce a status report warning](https://www.drupal.org/node/2869592)